# Endless loop of iCloud prompt rendering iPad unusable

Tags: ipad, icloud, wifi

I hadn't used my iPad in some time, and recently tried powering it back on.  As soon as iOS starts up, I am prompted to enter my iCloud password. My home WiFi network has changed since the last time I used the iPad, so there is no internet access.  The iPad won't accept what I believe to be the password for my Apple ID the last time I used it (I have since changed it, but imagine it's expecting me to enter a cached password since the device hasn't been in contact with Apple's servers in some time).

I'm unable to connect to my new WiFi network since the iCloud prompt appears every second after hitting cancel.  Is there any way out of this loop?  I've tried restoring the device via iTunes, but it tells me that that Find my iPad has to be disabled before doing a restore (which, of course, requires entering the iCloud password).

Answer (score 1):

I found a (much less than satisfactory) solution to the problem.  There is a slight delay between when pressing "cancel" on the iCloud password prompt and when the next popup opens.  I was able to navigate to the WiFi settings, and after a lot of frustration, was able to connect to my new wireless network.  After doing so, the prompt accepted my updated password.  Quite annoying.

Comment: Ultimately this did it for me too. Man did I feel lame though. Almost want to check out Androids next time around.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, in the future, you could just temporarily change your wifi back to the old settings that match the iPad, allow it to connect, and then when complete, change your wifi back to the new settings.

Comment: The old settings were actually the WiFi network from my old address, so unfortunately that wouldn't have been possible.